# Writing a Nth order matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to create a `n-by-n` that looks like this:

[image]

Where the coefficients `a1`,`a2`,......`an` are known in advance, and basically the order of matrix `n` is nothing but `length(a)`.

Few more examples of what I mean:

[image]

[image]

The only condition being `n >= 2`, because if `n == 1`, then the whole concept falls apart.

EDIT:
I want to multiply a variable to the last row of the matrix, but the order of the variable is dependent on the order of the matrix.

Say i want to multiply variable x to the last row.

[image]

Example:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this

```
N = 5;                      % size
last_row = rand(1,N);       % last row ( a_1,a_2,...,a_n )

A = diag(ones(N-1,1),1);    % place upper diagonal
A(N,:) = last_row;          % place last row
```

`diag(vector, k)` produce a matrix filled with zero's and `k`'th off diagonal as `vector`, in your case, 1's.

Then you can substitute last row as the known values.

The result is

```
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1
a b c d e
```

where `a,b,c,d,e` are random numbers contained in `last_row`.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for! my savior

Comment: Check operator starting with `.`. In your case, you can use  `last_row = (x.^(1:n)).*last_row`

Comment: This works only if it's (1:N). but i want to do it (N:1) which is invalid with this method

Comment: what i did was i saved (1:N) in a variable, then 'fliplr' and used it. this works, is there any elegant way of doing this

Answer (score 1):

A small variation on [**김도현**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38889444/3372061)'s answer, using [`eye`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eye.html) and [`circshift`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html):

```
N = 5;                % same as before
last_row = rand(1,N); % same as before

% Option 1
A = circshift(eye(N),1,2);
A(N,:) = last_row;    % same as before
```

A couple more options in case you want your output to be [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) (if you are unfamiliar with `sparse` see [MATLAB's documentation on their advantages](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/computational-advantages-of-sparse-matrices.html)):

```
% Option 2 (sparse)
A = gallery('tridiag', zeros(1,N-1), zeros(1,N), ones(1,N-1));
A(N,:) = last_row;    % same as before

% Option 3 (sparse, all-in-one, using the syntax "S = sparse(i,j,v)" )
A = sparse([1:N-1, N*ones(1,N)], [2:N, 1:N], [ones(1,N-1) last_row]);
```

Consider also: [`spdiags`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html) and [`speye`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/speye.html).

Comment: Even though your answer looks cleaner; I prefer @김도현 answer. it's easy to understand

Comment: @Ashok I didn't say 김도현's answer was bad, I'm just providing a different approach.

Comment: Yes, As i cannot accept 2 answers, i was just giving the reason why i did not accept your answer.

Comment: @Ashok Don't worry - it's ok. I know how things work around here :)

Comment: But stackoverflow doesn't stop me from upvoting you. So have my upvotes :)

Comment: @Ashok Thanks :) Note that I have edited the answer and also added a `sparse` variant of the array.

Comment: It seems that `triu` is unnecessary for the Option 2. Plus, it is better to use `A = gallery('tridiag',zeros(1,N-1),zeros(1,N),ones(1,N-1));` instead of add or multiply 0's. But your approach is good to learn how to assemble matrix!

Comment: @김도현 You are right about `triu`, I initially meant for the "tridiag" function to only accept a value for the diagonal and a size, and then you had to get rid of the two extra diagonals. Regarding `zeros` and `ones`, the method you suggested only works better starting [MATLAB R2015b](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance).. I'm not used to it yet :) In any case - I've edited the answer, so thanks!

Comment: quite interesting article. I think I need to test it on my machine, too. Thanks

Comment: @Dev-iL Can you take a look the edit I need to implement a small change.

Comment: @Ashok I'm afraid not. You should revert the edit, ask a new question, and link to this question in the new one. Changing your question after it was answered and accepted is VERY frowned upon on Stack Overflow. You can solve it using lastrow = bsxfun(@power,lastrow,N:-1:1)

Comment: I have couple of doubts with the lastrow = bsxfun(@power,lastrow,N:-1:1) , should i make new question?

Comment: @Ashok Definitely.